# I have a problem with a task on the computer language C

Tags: c

I would like to ask for assistance on a program I have to create on C.
The task is as it follows: To compile a program that enters integers m, n (m < n) and finds the number of all integers in this interval that are divisible by 3. The program displays all numbers that are in the interval and are not divisible by 3.

I managed to write the code on Python, but I have no idea how to do it on C.

I will appreciate every single help you send! Thanks in advance!

Comment: Take the [tour], read [ask], and post an [mcve]. Have you made any attempts at writing C code yet?

Comment: In each case [language], there are three steps: (1) get m,n from stdin, (2) loop on range(m,n+1) -> increment count `if ((x % 3) == 0)` (3) print count So, how do you get input (e.g. `scanf`)? What is the C equivalent of python: `for x in range(m,n + 1):`? (e.g. `for (int x = m;  x < (n + 1); ++x)`) What is the equivalent of `print("%d" % count)` (e.g. `printf("%d\n",count);`)? Start with basic "hello world" program: `#include <stdio.h> int main(void) { printf("hello world\n"); return 0; }`

Comment: Thank You for the fast reply! I managed to write it on Python, but i am unable to translate it to C. For the m, and n I need them to be from the console i.e input.

Comment: Look at the man pages. I've given you all the hints you need. How about `man scanf`?

Comment: Another hint: In python, _function_ scope variables have a default/safe initial value even if you don't specify one. In C, one has do provide an _explicit_ value even if it's declared: `int count;` does _not_ do this, but `int count = 0;` does. Compile with the `-Wall` command line option to enable warnings [always!].

Comment: One other hint: In python, if you do _not_ declare a variable before you use it in a function, it is considered local/function scope. For it to be global/common, you have to say: `global y`. In C, it's the reverse. If you do _not_ have a function scope definition for `y`, it defaults to file/global scope.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, I suggest you have a look at C's `printf`, `scanf` and loops, and then you should be fine!

However, here is a way to do it (in case you need a peek):

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) {
    int m, n;
    int counter = 0; 
    printf("Enter m: ");
    scanf("%d", &m); // reads from the standard input and puts the value into m
    /* The "%d" is to tell the program that we are going to read a signed decimal
     * integer.
     * Note: To keep the code simpler (i.e. without input checking or 
     * sanitization), we just assume that the user will input
     * valid integers, i.e. two integers m and n such that m < n.
     */
    printf("Enter n: ");
    scanf("%d", &n); // same for n


    /* Now you loop over all integers that are in the interval [m, n]
     * int i = m is the initialization of the loop, i.e. where you want to start
     * from.
     * i <= n is the condition of the loop, i.e. while i is smaller or equal to n
     * i++ is done in the end of an iteration, i.e. move onto the next integer 
     * at the end of each iteration.
     */ 
    printf("The numbers not divisible by 3 are:\n"); // \n means end of line
    for(int i = m; i <= n; i++) {
        if(i % 3 == 0) {
            counter++;
        }
        else {
            /* Note: If you are not printing a string (for example an 
             * integer in our case), C also requires the format "%d" (opposed to 
             * Python where one would have written print(i + " ")).
             */
            printf("%d ", i);
        }
    }
    printf("\n");
    printf("There are %d integers in [%d, %d] that are divisible by 3\n", 
        counter, m, n);
    return 0;
}
```